# Can't send email from my Godaddy Webmail in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I want to send email from my Godaddy webmail in Laravel project.

I have configured all the credentials perfectly and there is no connection related problem in Log file. But still mail is not sending

**.env file**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp    
MAIL_HOST=sg2plcpnl0003.prod.sin2.secureserver.net    
MAIL_PORT=465    
MAIL_USERNAME=info@ezmoverandrental.com    
MAIL_PASSWORD='my_web_mail_pass'    
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

**config/mail.php**

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),    
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'sg2plcpnl0003.prod.sin2.secureserver.net'),    
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),    
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'info@ezmoverandrental.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'test'),
    ],    
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),    
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

I can't find any solution.

If anyone have any query please feel free to ask.

Comment: It'll be hard to troubleshoot especially if the log file doesn't contain anything

Comment: I think you have to configure a mail server, your logs file must to have something.

Comment: @D0rm1nd0....I have configure this mail into my server. And my Log file doesn't show any kind of error !!

Answer (score 1):

On a shared hosting you have to use the native sendmail as a driver works mostly.

change  your mail driver to `mail` or `sendmail`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail    
MAIL_HOST=sg2plcpnl0003.prod.sin2.secureserver.net    
MAIL_PORT=465    
MAIL_USERNAME=info@ezmoverandrental.com    
MAIL_PASSWORD='eZia120$'    
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```